# curl extract answers in a stream

Tags: linux, bash, curl, libcurl

I'm sending a cURL request and get responses through a stream on which I can see all the answers as they arrived.

However, I'd like to extract each line to used them within a script.

Have you got any idea on how I can achieve that with bash, python or whatever ?

Thx

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow! please ask a more specific question, to target the specific issue you're having. also, try and search the site for similar questions before posting, as your issues have been discussed thoroughly on the site. cheerz :)

Comment: ^^^ and provide example of your curls. :)

Comment: probably something like: `<your curl stream command> <your url> | while read line; do <something> $line; done`